# Build errors in JDK 1.5 but not in 1.6 for Connection interface

Tags: jdbc

I have my class implementing the Connection interface, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html

I was not getting any build errors when I was testing it in one of my local machine, which is having JDK 1.6 version. But on deploying the same to another remote machine which is having JDK 1.5 version, its throwing 16 build errors saying "Cannot find symbol..."

The errors are throwing for the methods starting from createClob as displayed in the documentation page. Actually, in 1.6 version, I didn't implement those methods and so it threw the error saying, "The methods must be implemented". And So I implemented it as follows,

```
public Clob createClob() {
return conn.createClob();
}
```

But after building the same code in 1.5, its throwing, "Cannot find symbol..." build errors.

Is it because of version problem? Is there a way to correct the errors in 1.5 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [createClob()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createClob%28%29) method was added in Java 1.6 / JDBC 4.0. It is not available on the `Connection` interface in earlier versions of Java.

So you will either need to use a different class / implementation per Java version, or use a Proxy implementation instead of manually implementing each and every method.

BTW: What is it you are trying to achieve here? Unless you are implementing a JDBC driver, you usually would not need to implement `Connection` yourself.